# Cordova ionic - css animation doesnt work in galaxy s3

Tags: css, cordova, ionic-framework, css-animations

I have a animation css code and its working apart from galaxy s3.
How can I fix it?
CSS code:

```
    @keyframes animatedBackground {
    from { background-position: 0 0; }
    to { background-position: 100% 0; }
}
.animation-area {
    width: 560px; 
    height: 400px; 
    background-image: url(../img/cloud.png);
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;

    animation: animatedBackground 40s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: This is probably due to the old version of the webview rendering the app. If you don't want to bother with this, you can use Crosswalk that will add a browser for the webview with your app. The result will be : no issue with old version of Android for CSS and Javascript but increase app size a lot (30MB)

Comment: Under what version is this happening?